# Location Consent & undo Remeber This Setting

Tags: settings, permissions, location-services

Like many, I found the Location Consent prompts to be annoying. I was excited when Google finally extended the option to 'remember this setting' in the latest update, but dismayed when I could only have the phone remember a 'yes' answer.

Unfortunately, when I handed the phone to a friend to coordinate GPS while driving she checked 'Remember this setting' and consented into the program. I would like to undo this, but cannot for the life of me find where this setting is stored on my phone. It does not appear to be listed in the 'Location' or by clearing the cache of the LocationServices app (which doesn't appear to actually work)

How can this be undone? Phone is a Motorola Razr HD running 4.4.2

Answer (score 5):

geffchang's answer is correct. That said, it is meant for a rooted Android so users of non-rooted Android devices may not find it of much use.

Those users, if willing to sacrifice third-part apps' data associated with their Google account, can consider clearing data of Play services' app as a solution.

Set location mode to Device only for once, disable location mode, launch Settings app → Apps → All apps → Google Play services → Force stop → Manage Space → Clear data → Force stop again → optionally reboot.

Now try enabling the location mode. It should default to Device only and should you attempt to change to High accuracy, that [Improve location accuracy?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VGfb.png) dialog for agreement would be shown to you.

Comment: i just had to do this in android 6.0.1. this is confirmed by me as working solution for android 6. there is no loss of data visible to the user.

Comment: This solution was suggested for my (duplicate) question and I can confirm it worked in 5.0.2 and it didn't appear to affect my data

Comment: I tried this solution and it did not work at first, Tried it a second time and it worked.
The second time I left GPS only enabled with GPS on when I rebooted.
That did the trick. When the phone rebooted GPS was still in GPS only mode and when I turn GPS off then back on I got the "Improve location accuracy prompt again"

Comment: The Force Stop option was greyed out for me, so I avoided that step but this process still worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you have root access, edit this file:
`data > data > com.google.android.gms > shared_prefs > nlp-prefs.xml`

Change the value of `confirmNlp` to `true`.
`<boolean name="confirmNlp" value="false" />`

[Source](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/reset-google-network-location-consent-t2890971).

Comment: And I reached this conclusion by matching the file differences in Play services' data directory before and after agreeing for that dialog. That was the only file that was created after agreeing.